# Apple Rejection: Invalid Launch Image

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know what this message means from Apple:

> "iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for
>   iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted
>   must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a
>   launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about iPhone 5
>   support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines."
>
> "Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size
>   modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or
>   later"

I am using **Xcode Version 4.2** and **Base SDK 5.0**

The launch images I've created are as such:

- `Default.png` (320 x 480)
- `Default@2x.png` (640 x 960)
- `Default-568h@2x.png` (640 x 1136)

Comment: Base SDK 5.0 != iOS 6.0 SDK

Comment: Why are you still using Xcode 4.2 and SDK 5.0 as Base SDK? You have to update to a recent version (Xcode 4.5 at least, since this is the earliest Xcode that supports iOS 6.0) to submit the app. If you are still on Snow Leopard you are out of luck.

Comment: Try updating to the new iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Same here... I will try to implement iOS 6 SDK.

Answer (score 7):

1. As of May 1 2013 you need iPhone 5 support in your app. Otherwise it'll be rejected.
2. To get iPhone 5 Support you have to use the iOS 6.0 SDK to compile your app.
3. To use the iOS 6.0 SDK you need at least Xcode 4.5

And Xcode 4.5 needs at least OS X Lion.

So if you are still on Snow Leopard it's time to update to Lion or Mountain Lion.
If your computer is not capable of running one of the two latest OS' it's time to buy a new Mac.

If you need to buy a new Mac get one that is capable of running Mountain Lion. Wikipedia tells me that Xcode 5 (which you have to use to get iOS 7 SDK) does not run on Lion.

Comment: It's a really bad situation :/